# Is there a way to retrieve a light JSON version of a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: json, google-sheets

My app is showing points of interest on a map, the records are stored in a google spreadsheet then retreived using the "Publish spreadsheet" feature.

With 1900 points google generate a 1.9MB JSON that weight 150KB once gzipped. That is so heavy that browser halt a second while parsing it. This is far too much for my taste, especialy considering that it is full of duplicate information and the meaningfull data in it is only 200KB, 50KB gzipped.

Here is Google the JSON for one record :

```
   {  
   "id":{  
      "$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/ < KEY >< KEY >< KEY >< KEY >< KEY >/od6/public/values/ciyn3"
   },
   "updated":{  
      "$t":"2014-09-04T07:09:37.316Z"
   },
   "category":[  
      {  
         "scheme":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006",
         "term":"http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list"
      }
   ],
   "title":{  
      "type":"text",
      "$t":"5"
   },
   "content":{  
      "type":"text",
      "$t":"date: 2009, address: 45 random street, CP: 27600, city: CityName, completeAddress: 45 random street\u003c/br\u003eCityName\u003c/br\u003e2009, gps: 49.1547694, 1.2469558"
   },
   "link":[  
      {  
         "rel":"self",
         "type":"application/atom+xml",
         "href":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/< KEY >< KEY >< KEY >< KEY >< KEY >/od6/public/values/ciyn3"
      }
   ],
   "gsx$id":{  
      "$t":"5"
   },
   "gsx$date":{  
      "$t":"2009"
   },
   "gsx$address":{  
      "$t":"45 random street"
   },
   "gsx$CP":{  
      "$t":"27600"
   },
   "gsx$city":{  
      "$t":"CityName"
   },
   "gsx$completeAddress":{  
      "$t":"45 random street\u003c/br\u003eCityName\u003c/br\u003e2009"
   },
   "gsx$gps":{  
      "$t":"49.1547694, 1.2469558"
   }
}
```

Why do they put so much metadata that is reapeated for each record ?

Is there a way to retreive a lighter version of the spreadsheet from Google ?

---

Please do not tell me to retrieve the JSON and parse it on my server (that's what I do usually but it's not my question here).

Comment: how do you retrieve the json in the first place? and show us your spreadsheet structure and desired json output layout.

Comment: @user3616725 : By using the publish spreadsheet feature. It makes a public link to retrieve the data as JSON, JSON in script, XML...